# I can not login to ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

After installation, system requierd resart now. After the restart system directly login to windows 8. I can not see the ubuntu for choose to login.

Answer (score 0):

1.Log in into your windows 8 os.Download and install EasyBCD from [*`here`*.](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/EasyBCD-Download-45820.html)

2.Under linux section,set grub2 as bootloader add a boot entry for your Ubuntu Partition.
And also add entry for your windows 8 partition.

3.reboot

Or

try [`boot-repair disk`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) .
Manual: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair